# Why does the put and let statements need to be prefixed by a % sign in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS, why cannot we write

```
let name = abc;
put "&name";
```

Why do we have to include the % sign like this:

```
%let name = abc;
%put &name;
```

Imagine I am writing the statements in the main body of the code, not inside a data step.

Also, is the second way of writing it same as:

```
%macro test;
%let name = abc;
%put &name; 
%mend;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%let` and `%put` are part of the SAS macro language.  Macro language statements are (with one or two particular exceptions) prefixed by `%` to tell the SAS macro parser to operate on them.

They do entirely different things from the non-`%` version - except when it works out to the same thing.  You *can* write `put "&mvar.";` - as long as it's in a data step (As that's a data step statement).  Macro commands/functions/statements are allowed in open code sometimes (and not in others).

Writing it inside an actual macro is more-or-less the same.  There are scoping issues, though; `&name` won't be available outside of that macro, unless it's been declared global.

Answer (score 2):

The `%LET` and `%PUT` statements are part of the SAS macro processor and not part of base SAS. The `%` (and `&`) triggers are what activate the macro processor and allow it to recognize that these strings need be processed before they are passed to the SAS compiler/interpreter.

You cannot use an assignment statement like

```
x = 3.5 ;
```

outside of a data step (or some proc that support these types of statements).

To your second question, if you wrap the macro statements inside of a macro definition then the main impact will be.

1. The macro variable `NAME` will be defined as local to the macro if it does not already exist.
2. Nothing will happen until you invoke the macro.  The `%macro` statement begins the definition of a macro.  So all of the code up to the corresponding `%mend` statement define the macro.  To execute it you will need to invoke the macro using syntax like `%test`.